# How To Request An Erronous Resume Be Updated Or Removed

Tags: resume, email, manager, cover-letter, hiring

Well I really messed up: A small batch of custom resumes were perfect and typo free, however, they were not converted to PDF correctly and as a result there was additional personal information from another document included at the bottom of the resume. The mistake is obvious and will most likely result in receiving no call backs from these employers; this field is unforgiving of these types of errors that scream incompetence. My question is that while there is nothing I can do to correct the mistake and become a "serious candidate", I would like to at least get the sloppy resume updated in their database, so as to remove the personal information as well as hopefully prevent it from being seen in the future, in case I have later dealings with these companies.

Is a short letter saying "I made a mistake and would appreciate it if they could replace the faulty resume with the correct one" appropriate or understandbale? Please note that these resumes were emailed, not uploaded into a web-based database (otherwise I would just update it myself). Will an HR Manager even do this? Anything else to add in order to soften the blow... like a note taking responsibility for the mistake and an apology for the inconvenience?

Comment: How did you manage that? Most HR I know wouldn't bother doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you don't want the companies to keep your faulty resumes. I would send them an e-mail that apparently something went wrong with the export and that I should have checked it again, and I'd ask if they can replace it with the updated CV.

You said the error is too obvious, so admit your mistake and proactively make things right. I'm not sure if an HR manager does something about it, but you can always try. If you don't try they will keep your faulty resumes (or throw it away).